# Bash: fill file template with input and save to new location

Tags: bash

I have a file like this:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${password}
    ports:
      - '1234:1234'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/datav2
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Inside a batch script I read this file in:

```
TEMPLATE=$(<./path_to/docker-compose.yml)
```

Now I ask the user to pass in a password with

```
echo 'Setup password : '
read -s password
```

So now there is the variable `$password`. No I need to inject this variable into the $TEMPLATE variable, as you see there is already a `${password}` in the template.
After this, I need to write the file to a new location. However, the following does not work:

```
sudo /bin/bash -c "echo ${TEMPLATE} >> /home/new.yml"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can just skip reading `TEMPLATE` and run `envsubst <./path-to/docker-compose.yml > /home/new.yml`

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `envsub` as follow to substitute environment variable(s):

```bash
envsubst < "./path_to/docker-compose.yml" > /home/new.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `envsubst` directly:

```bash
$ cat file
version: 3.4
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${password}
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/datav2
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

```bash
$ export password=foo
$ envsubst < file
version: 3.4
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foo
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/datav2
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```